# Empty xpage when not have acces to document

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a xpage that have control of the documents by readers field.
The control works fine, but when a user does not have access to a document and try to access this document direct by URL, the page show a empty xpage for read only. 
This is hard for user to understand.
When a user cant see a document I need to show a error page "You dont have access...." instead a empty xpage.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the datasource document is nothing, when the user don't have access to document.
If I am right, you can create two panels.
The first with an label/an error message in it and 
the second with your xpages / your document fields and description.

Than you have edit the visible property of the first panel to

```
!doc
```

and the visible property of the second panel to

```
doc
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, when I check the datasource(doc) return something when the user have access or not. I check with doc.getDocument()